# Left panel in the sphinx documentation is collapsing every time I click on something

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx

I am working on Sphnix documentation :

for my project index.rst looks like :

```
Table of Contents
--------------------------------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :titlesonly:

   sphnix_toolbox.testing
   ...
```

here sphnix_toolbox.testing is the rst files.

Now sphnix_toolbox.testing.rst looks like:

```
Source
----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   Sphnix
   run_setup
   ...
```

These are also rst files.

Just for the example I am showing this image:
[image]

So my problem is when I am clicking anything on the left panel for e.g check_asset_copy. left panel was colapsing to the default.
Like this

[image]

I want it to collapse only when I click on something outside sphnix_toolbox.testing or anything else. It was collapsing everytime I click on anything from the left panel.

Currenlty using `html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"`.

Comment: When I click on `check_asset_copy` here, https://sphinx-toolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/testing.html, the left panel (sidebar) does not collapse.

Comment: Yes, that was for example. I was having the same scenario. due NDA I can't show u the exact data. But in my case left panel was collapsing every time.

Comment: I was missing ```collapse_navigation=True``` in the conf.py file. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this link :

https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuring.html

use toc options.

```
'collapse_navigation': True,
'sticky_navigation': True,
```

Sticky will maintain the context in the Left panel.